# line integral of a function

Tags: line-integrals

I have to calculate the integral  $$\int_{K}xy \cdot dx $$ along the curve K with equation $y=x^2$ at which $x$ varies from $1$ to $2$. 
I don't know how to begin answering this question.

Comment: Have you calculated line integrals before? It's useful to read to Wikipedia page ...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral

Comment: @MattiP. I did, but can't really understand the question. I know how to calculate these kind of questions when there are parametric equations, but not when its formulated like this.

Comment: Parametrize the curve with (for instance) $x=t$, $y=t^2$ and $dx=dt$ where $1\leq t\leq2$.